# How do I get wordpress to override a previous posts query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a page that has a category list at the top, and should normally list posts below it. The category list is created using:

```
<?php $display_categories = array( 4, 7, 8, 9, 21, 1); $i = 1;
    foreach ( $display_categories as $category ) { ?>
        <div>
            <?php single_cat_title(); ?> //etc
        </div>
    <?php } 
?>
```

However, this seems to make the post loop order posts by category. I want it to ignore category ordering and order by date in descending order. I've created a new WP_Query since according to the docs you can't use query_posts() twice, so just in case.

```
<?php $q = new WP_Query( "cat=-1&showposts=15&orderby=date&order=DESC" );
    if ( $q->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post(); ?>
            the_title(); // etc
        endwhile; 
    endif; 
?>
```

However, this **still** seems to be ordered by category (the same order as the list above) and then by date, as opposed to just by date.

Comment: I've got sunshiiiine...on a cloudy day...

Comment: I wish I had a page.  All I've got is the ability to form coherent sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had problems with this before as well.

Try this:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $myposts = get_posts( 'numberposts=5' );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <div <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <div class="title">
                <h2>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h2>
                <p class="small"><?php the_time( 'F j, Y' ); ?> by <?php the_author(); ?></p>
             </div>
             <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
         </div>
     <?php endforeach; 
 ?>
```

The important line is `global $post;`.

That should reset your global query.  The `setup_postdata($post)` method is necessary to give you access to functions like `the_author()` or `the_content()`.

-Chris

Answer (score 0):

query_posts is finicky sometimes.  Try something like this and see if it works:

```
query_posts(array('category__not_in'=>array(1),
                  'showposts'=>15,
                  'orderby'=>date,
                  'order'=>DESC));
```

Since that's not the issue, try adding update_post_caches($posts) to the second loop, like this:

```
<?php $q = new WP_Query("cat=-1&showposts=15&orderby=date&order=DESC");
if ( $q->have_posts() ) : while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post(); update_post_caches($posts); ?>
the_title(); // etc
endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Supposedly this [solves some plugin problems](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_Example_3_-_Plugins).

Comment: Thanks for answering! That doesn't seem to make any difference, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with wordpress, but a couple of possibilities:

1. You define the "order" parameter twice in the string you're calling `query_posts()` with, I don't know if that causes a problem or not.
2. As well, "show" is not a valid parameter, you may have been looking for "showposts".

Parameters and their effects are described here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Parameters

Comment: Hi, thanks for noticing those. I've updated the code (and the post above), but it still doesn't seem to fix the issue.